Load deep learning model by URL without downloading to local machine
I have some large pickle files on my server and can be accessed by a static HTTP URL. Currently, I have to manually download files to local machine and load them to FastAPI, like the following code:
import requests
import tqdm

def download_file(url, save_path):
    block_size = 1024
    file_name = url.split("/")[-1]
    try:
        headers = {}
        response = requests.request(
            "HEAD",
            url,
            headers=headers,
        )
        if response.status_code != 200:
            return None
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            total = int(response.headers["Content-Length"], 0)
            resp = requests.get(
                url,
                headers=headers,
                stream=True,
            )
            with open(save_path, "wb") as file, tqdm(
                desc=save_path,
                total=total,
                unit="B",
                unit_scale=True,
                unit_divisor=1024,
            ) as bar:
                for data in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=block_size):
                    size = file.write(data)
                    bar.update(size)

            return total
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise e

I would like to call and load those files directly from server instead of downloading them to local machine. Any better methods or approaches for this?

I would suggest you uvicorn you can look up the docs , so you can take advantage of using async which might be an over kill, but I am suspecting your server also handles other requests which might be the case in the real world , this code is not tested but more or less a guide, as I don't have the pickle file, nevertheless the logic remains same.

first install uvicorn


pip install uvicorn


Here is the code that should help

from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
import aiohttp
import pickle
from io import BytesIO

app = FastAPI()

async def load_pickle_from_url_async(url):
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                response.raise_for_status()
                data = await response.read()
                obj = pickle.load(BytesIO(data))
        return obj
    except aiohttp.ClientError as e:
        raise HTTPException(....)
    except Handle pickle error:
        raise HTTPException(..)

@app.get("/path/to/where/your/data/lives/")
async def load_data_from_server():
    url = "http://yourserver.com/yourfile.pkl"
    data = await load_pickle_from_url_async(url)
    return  data # you can do anything with the data here


How to run it

uvicorn name_of_your_module_name:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --workers 4


is 'data' returned from load_data_from_server a vector?

Hi @8589934592 a vector? it cant. I would imagine it is your pickle file or files in your pickle, did you run the code?

Also, pickle files are updated every day to server. Can uvicorn load new pickle files from server and release the old one without reloading FastAPI?

my pickle file stores an array of millions vectors

Hi @8589934592 whatever you would want univorn to do it will do, so far what you parse to it is a pickle file(it could be a ziilion of vector, or model) in this case . As for your second question you are asking? FASTAPI is an api so if you use any of its endpoints like visit /api/load_data or make an endpoint request to it via uvicorn server which calls the endpoint, it will definitely trigger, but I would imagine there is a way to mitigate against it, if you look at the docs, there would be a way to do what you are asking for. Does this help? to be fair your question is two in one haha!

@8589934592 you can look at this link https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/repeated-tasks/ also increase your workers to 8 to make processing faster
